# Restore plain text postgresql using batch file

Tags: database, postgresql, batch-file, restore, psql

I want to restore a plain postgres backup, im doing it via psql.exe using this commands:

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.0\bin\" <br>
psql -h 192.168.10.160 -p 5432 db_name postgres
```

then cmd displays `db_name=#` ,and I type, `\i 'C:/Backup.sql'` and the restore is done

Is there a way to do it using a batch file?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22221929/1216680)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use the `-f` option to read from a file:

```
psql -h 192.168.10.160 -p 5432 -f C:\Backup.sql db_name postgres
```

Answer (score 0):

When I do this I set the pgdump to include the database name in the sql before all the create tables

\connect mydatabasename