# In PostgreSQL, how to insert data with COPY command?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, bulk-load, postgresql-copy

I have problem when run 1 project NodeJs with PostgreSQL database.
I have error when trying to insert data in pgAdmin using the `COPY` command.

```
COPY beer (name, tags, alcohol, brewery, id, brewery_id, image) FROM stdin;

Bons Voeux  blonde  9.5 Brasserie Dupont    250 130 generic.png
```

This data in
[gist](https://github.com/ccoenraets/belgian-beer-explorer/blob/master/beers.sql):

This error:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "Bons"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 1967
```

[image: I was create database like this and execute file .sql:]

Comment: This kind of error depends on the type of database framework that you are using. You should include such detail in your question.

Comment: @vitaly-t, I was update gif file method create 1 database and execute file beers.sql but have error.

Comment: You seem to have mislabeled your question with node.js and javascript labels, that do not pertain to your question. That's the reason I asked for clarification.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18737107/1216680) OR you can restore your plain backup (that containes copy from stdin) using psql like shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22221929/1216680)

Comment: The animated gif turned out to be helpful.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

```
COPY tbl FROM STDIN;
```

is not supported by pgAdmin.
You get a plain syntax error because Postgres gets the data as SQL code.

***Four*** possible solutions:

#### 1. Use a multi-row `INSERT` instead:

```sql
INSERT INTO beer(name, tags, alcohol, brewery, id, brewery_id, image)
VALUES 
  ('Bons Voeux', 'blonde', 9.5, 'Brasserie Dupont', 250, 130, 'generic.png')
, ('Boerke Blond', 'blonde', 6.8, 'Brouwerij Angerik', 233, 287 'generic.png')
;
```

Note the different (SQL) syntax for values as string or numeric literals.

You can generate the data with [`pg_dump` using `--inserts`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html). See:

- [Export specific rows from a PostgreSQL table as INSERT SQL script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12815496/export-specific-rows-from-a-postgresql-table-as-insert-sql-script/12816187)

#### 2. Use psql as privileged system user

Call your script on the command line using `psql`. As system user `postgres`:

```bash
psql -f beer.sql -U my_login_role -d db_name
```

Database (`-d`) and login role (`-U` for "User") can be omitted if defaults are ok. Syntax examples:

- [Create Postgres database using batch file with [template],[encoding],[owner] and a .sql file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208181/create-postgres-database-using-batch-file-with-template-encoding-owner-and/8208821#8208821)

Be sure there is an end-of-data marker (`\.`) for default `text` format. (You have that.) [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html#AEN71940)

> End of data can be represented by a single line containing just
> backslash-period (`\.`). An end-of-data marker is not necessary when
> reading from a file, since the end of file serves perfectly well; it
> is needed only when copying data to or from client applications using
> pre-3.0 client protocol.

#### 3. `COPY` on the db server with privileged DB role

Move your data to a separate file ***on the server***, like 'beer_data.csv', and use `COPY ... FROM 'filename'` in your script:

```
COPY beer (name, tags, alcohol, brewery, id, brewery_id, image)
FROM '/path/to/beer_data.csv';
```

You need superuser privileges, though. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html)

> [...] `COPY` naming a file or command is only allowed to database superusers
> or users who are granted one of the default roles
> `pg_read_server_files`, `pg_write_server_files`, or
> `pg_execute_server_program`, since it allows reading or writing any file
> or running a program that the server has privileges to access.

(`pg_read_server_files`, `pg_write_server_files` and `pg_execute_server_program` are new in Postgres 11.)

#### 4. `\copy` on any client

Read a file local to the ***client*** with the [psql meta-command `\copy`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-COPY). See:

- [How to update selected rows with values from a CSV file in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910494/how-to-update-selected-rows-with-values-from-a-csv-file-in-postgres/8910810#8910810)
- [How to use \copy in postgresql with pgadmin4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41196030/how-to-use-copy-in-postgresql-with-pgadmin4/41196126#41196126)

Comment: `pg_dump --inserts <database> > dump.sql` did it for me, thanks!

Comment: With "psql beer -f beer.sql" the consol asked me : PASSWORD FOR USER -f : i dont understand....

Comment: @JulienBaldy: Sorry, I fixed the psql call.

Comment: Second Step, Worked!

Answer (score 6):

First step is to create the Database `belgianbeers` on pgAdmin.

Then open prompt and run `psql -U postgres -d belgianbeers -a -f beers.sql`

This command line running e update database tables.

Note: `-U postgres` = specifies `postgres` as the username

Answer (score 1):

My Resolution: Put the SQL file in your root directory, e.g. `C:\`.

For example my database is called `cities` and my SQL file is `cidade.sql`.

Open `cmd` inside the BIN folder in your PostgreSQL directory and type:

```
psql -U postgres -d cities < C:\cidade.sql
```

The arguments to `psql` are:

- `-U [user]`
- `-d [database]`

You will be prompted for your password. Do not forget to check if `psql` is in your environment variables `%PATH%`.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections, first time answering, I didn't know how to deal with the formatting.