# How to use \copy in postgresql with pgadmin4

Tags: postgresql, csv, psql, postgresql-copy, pgadmin-4

I want to use the `\copy` command to make csv file with relative path.
I used a query to make from test table to csv file named test.csv

```
\copy (SELECT * FROM test) to './test.csv' with csv
```

But in postgresql pgadmin4, it shows that `\copy` command as a syntax error (there is an underline under the word '\copy') and shows a message like below.

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "/"
> LINE 2: /copy (SELECT * FROM test) to './persons_client.csv' with cs...
>         ^
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: syntax error at or near "/"
> SQL state: 42601
> Character: 2
> ```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 11):

[`\copy`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS) is a meta-command of the default command-line interface [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html). You cannot run it from the "Query Tool" of pgAdmin4 (or any other SQL client). Run it from psql instead. (You can open a "PSQL tool" in modern pgAdmin4.)

psql's `\copy` is a client-side wrapper for the SQL-command [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html). If you have access to the database server (and the necessary privileges) you may be able to use SQL `COPY` instead.

Comment: "You can open a "PSQL tool" in modern pgAdmin4" how about mentioning how?

Answer (score 5):

What I did to solve this problem was to execute:

```
psql=# copy tmp from '/path/to/file.csv' with delimiter ',' csv header encoding 'windows-1251';
```