# Rails seed sql file that contains "COPY" statments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to seed sql file that looks like that:

```sql
COPY courses (id, name, "courseID", school_id, created_at, updated_at) FROM stdin;
1 Fundamentals of Programming CSCI150 1 2016-04-27 14:04:07.460825  2016-04-27 14:04:07.460825
```

I try this code:

```ruby
connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
# migrate all courses
sql = File.read('db/nurate.sql')
statements = sql.split(/;$/)
#statements.pop
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  statements.each do |statement|
    connection.execute(statement)
  end
end
```

Previously I used this code for INSERT etc statements. But here I have error as follows:

> PG::UnableToSend: another command is already in progress

So Believe this has something to do with the fact that my sql dump file contains "COPY" statements. What can I do with this? I don't want to change the whole file to use INSERT statements. Or is it the only solution?

Answer (score 1):

I've got same issue and it costed me couple of days.

Firstly I guess that you've used the sql from dump export feature of postgres. So because of that when ever you call

```
connection.execute(statement)
```

It will cause error because it's never been a legit call for query in postgresql with provide input data. I've done some check over internet. It seem this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32271378/in-postgresql-how-to-insert-data-with-copy-command) provide some helpful information.

Okei so in order to keep using buck copy combine with the sql file export by pg_dump, I have come up with quite dirty code (IMO)

```
unless Rails.env.production?
  connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
  connection.tables.each do |table|
    connection.execute("TRUNCATE #{table}") unless table == "schema_migrations"
  end

  # Create a sql file with purely COPY data and ignoring schema_migrations data
  cmd = %x[awk -v RS='' '/COPY/{if (!match($0,/schema/)) print $0}' #{Rails.root}/db/dump.sql> #{Rails.root}/db/temp.sql]
  puts cmd

  # Restoring sql data to postgres data. Putting password to env variable is never been smart
  cmd = %x[PGPASSWORD=#{ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config[:password]} psql --host #{ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config[:host]} -U #{ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config[:username]} --dbname #{ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config[:database]} -1 -f #{Rails.root}/db/temp.sql]
  puts cmd

  # remove the deed
  cmd = %x[rm #{Rails.root}/db/temp.sql]
  puts cmd

end
```