# Create Table on postgresql using information from excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, postgresql

Need to extract values from excel to a table in postgresql.
Example- excel table format data Table 1

```
Time       Flow
12:01 AM   30
12:02 AM   60
```

...
PostgreSQL table 2

```
Time       Price  Flow
12:01 AM    $1     ?(take from the excel sheet)
12:02 AM    $2     ?
```

Created a table 2 on postgresql and converted into dataframe.
Trying to read values from the excel sheet table 1 to fit data into table 2

PostgreSQL table 2

```
Time       Price  Flow
12:01 AM    $1     30(taken from the excel sheet table 1 flow column)
12:02 AM    $2     60
```

Comment: So what is your question? Is there any code you have a problem with?

Answer (score 0):

Save the Excel spreadsheet as CSV file. Delimitor, quote character etc. must match,  Doing that with LibreOffice, standard options just work ..

Then `COPY` or \copy to a temp table and `UPDATE table2` from there:

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_x ("Time" time, flow int);

-- in psql!
\copy tmp_x FROM '/path/to/file.csv' WITH (FORMAT csv, HEADER, NULL '\N', DELIMITER E'\t');

UPDATE table2 t
SET    flow = x.flow
FROM   tmp_x x
WHERE  t."Time" = x."Time";
```

`"Time"` must be unique, of course.

Related, with more details:

- [How to update selected rows with values from a CSV file in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910494/how-to-update-selected-rows-with-values-from-a-csv-file-in-postgres/8910810#8910810)

About `COPY` / `\copy`

- [In PostgreSQL, how to insert data with COPY command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32271378/in-postgresql-how-to-insert-data-with-copy-command/32279203#32279203)