# postgres dump file missing column in COPY

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Dump file*.sql gives error

```
ERROR:  missing data for column "year"
CONTEXT:  COPY entity_temporal, line 1: "Stroud_railway_station {1947, 1845, 1886} {1, 1, 1}"
```

My table name is `entity_temporal` with three column `Name text`, `year integer[]` and `count integer[]`.
The dump command looks like

```
COPY entity_temporal (name, year, count) FROM stdin;
Stroud_railway_station {1947, 1845, 1886} {1, 1, 1}
```

Comment: the dump file looks like this COPY entity_temporal (name, year, count) FROM stdin;
Stroud_railway_station {1947, 1845, 1886} {1, 1, 1}
Pakistani_cricket_team_in_New_Zealand_in_1964–65 {1964, 1965} {1, 1}
Peel_Z-1_Glider_Boat {1930, 2011, 1927} {1, 1, 1}
Julius_von_Borsody {1920, 1922, 1923, 1892, 1925, 1958, 1927, 1960, 1931, 1900, 1933, 1934, 1935, 1938, 1945, 1924, 1946, 1917} {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1}
Sibley_State_Park {1938, 1935} {1, 1}
Basilica_of_St._Louis_de_Montfort {1996} {1}
Chief_Justice_of_Lahore_High_Court {2015} {1}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see is your data is not properly formatted. There should be **tab space** between every *column values* and **next line** for *new row*.

You can read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32271378/in-postgresql-how-to-insert-data-with-copy-command) , the question provide links to the file which containing the proper data format.