# COPY from stdin PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I am having a hard time with this bulk copy syntax. Looks to me like I followed the correct syntax from a tutorial i checked out. But there seems to be a syntax error that i cannot detect. Need some help on this.

```
COPY aza_ods_version2.test2 
    FROM {'/Users/kevingitonga/Desktop/test1.csv' | STDIN} 
    [ [ WITH ]
          [ BINARY ]
          [ OIDS ]
          [ DELIMITER [ AS ] ',' ]
          [ CSV [ HEADER ]]
```

Comment: At my first glance, aren't you missing one `]` at the end ? Here is one useful so link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32271378/in-postgresql-how-to-insert-data-with-copy-command and the official document https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-copy.html#:~:text=%5Ccopy%20invokes%20COPY%20FROM%20STDIN,specified%20as%20an%20absolute%20path.

Comment: The `[` and `]` should **not** be entered - they just document [optional parameters](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/notation.html). See [the examples](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html#id-1.9.3.55.10) in the manual