# pg-restore unsupported version in file header

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore

I want to move a database from one machine to another but I get an error.  The source has a slightly older version of Postgres.  I started out using PGAdmin (because I thought that what I wanted to do was as common as breathing) and dropped back to using command line because "Failed (exit code:1)" that PGAdmin 4 was giving me was not helpful.

So from the source computer:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin>pg_dump --version
pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 10.7

C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\runtime\pg_dump.exe --file "C:\\PGData\\WellData.tar" --host "localhost" --port "5432" --username "postgres" --no-password --verbose --format=t --blobs "WellData"
```

And on the destination computer

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin>pg_restore.exe --host "localhost" --port "5432" --username "postgres" --no-password --dbname "WellData" --section=data --verbose "E:\\PGData\\WellData.tar"
pg_restore: [archiver] unsupported version (1.14) in file header

C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin>pg_restore --version
pg_restore (PostgreSQL) 10.8
```

I would rather understand the problem and fix it than work around it, but I did try backing up the data as SQL.  When I found that running the restore SQL statement would not work because it did not like the \N values that were used to indicate null values I gave up.  (the backup uses notation that the restore cannot handle?  That doesn't seem right)

Comment: What was the complete `pg_restore` command you gave that caused the error? Does '...backing up the data as SQL ' mean as plaint text? If so what was the restore procedure you used in that case, hint you can't use `pg_restore`. Add answers as update to your question.

Comment: Sorry.  I did not start my inserted code on a new line, so it did not appear.  Restore command now shows up.

Comment: 1) The dump was done using `C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\runtime\pg_dump.exe` not the `pg_dump` from the `\bin` directory. I would try doing the dump using the `\bin` version. 2) You have not explained '...backing up the data as SQL '. If this was indeed as plain text, then how did you try to restore it?

Comment: The Plain Text backup option generates SQL.  When I used that backup option, I ran that SQL to restore it.  My description was an attempt to balance clarity against explaining what is already familiar to those that understand the process.

Comment: But you said that restoring the plain text version did not work: 'When I found that running the restore SQL statement would not work because it did not like the \N values that were used to indicate null values I gave up.'

Comment: I found the answer to my SQL problem. 
 I was using PGAdmin which creates a COPY FROM stdin statement and appends the table being exported.  Thanks to this question and answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32271378/in-postgresql-how-to-insert-data-with-copy-command I now know that PGAdmin can't handle that.  Copying and pasting the data into a text file (excluding the end of data marker) and then running a  copy from statement that references that text file works just fine.  That still leaves the original question of why PGAdmin is not backing up a database to and from a TAR file.

Comment: Not sure what that link is supposed to be showing me? If you mean to point out that the `pgAdmin` query editor is broken then yes that is the case, but `pgAdmin` is not Postgres  it is just a client. If you want to restore the plain text use `psql`.

Comment: You have to quit thinking of `pgAdmin` as Postgres, it is not it is just a rather clunky client. The `COPY FROM stdin` is coming from `pg_dump`. Again `pgAdmin` is not creating the tar file `pg_dump` is.  Also again try using `pg_dump` from the 'bin\' directory not the 'runtime\' directory.