# Importing CSV into existing table

Tags: postgresql, powershell

I am trying to put data into a table in Postgres DB.
Schema and table already exist. All I want is to use file as input source that could be insert into that table.

I used modules like SqlServer if you ask, here is a quick glimpse of that part of the script:

```
Import-Module SqlServer
$connectionString =  Invoke-Sqlcmd -Username "USERNAME" -Password "PASSWORD" -Server "SERVERNAME" -Database "DATABASE_NAME" 
Write-SqlTableData -DatabaseName "DASHBOARD_NAME" -SchemaName "SCHEMA_NAME" -TableName "TABLE_NAME" -Force -InputData -Path 'PATH WHERE THE FILE IS STORED'
```

Comment: Use the SQL `COPY` command or the psql meta-command `\copy`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32279203/939860 (How is an SQLServer module relevant to this? Different RDBMS ...)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter thanks for answer. How it is relevant? Well, I tried to use PostgreSQLCmdlets module. I have a feeling that it would work, but this module demands a valid licence key to use. For obvious reason, I want my script to run every time I want to and not bother with licence expiration.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter you were right - SQLServer module is not relevant for Postgre DB.

Answer (score -1):

**You can use the LOAD DATA INFILE statement in MySQL.** **LOAD DATA INFILE**

LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/file.csv'
INTO TABLE table_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;

Comment: I am not sure if this is compatible with my module, to be honest.

Comment: Oh okay, am sorry that my **answer** couldn't _help_

Comment: As the answer is dealing with MySQL and the OP is dealing with Postgres you should just delete the answer.